# Affine function domain and range

Tags: affine-geometry

[image]

Could somebody what $\mathbb{K}$ signifies in the function definition ? 
If it was $\mathbb{R}$ it could mean Real space

Comment: $\mathbb K$ is apparently a field over which we have an inner product space; e.g., $\mathbb K=\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I don't think that it can be $\mathbb C$ because in the definition of the half-space you need an ordered field. And $\mathbb C$ can't be ordered.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net:  I see what you mean

Comment: @spaul Where is his coming from? Because I think that there is a mistake in the half-space definition. It shouldn't be $\vec{a}.\vec{x} \le \vec{b}$ but $\vec{a}.\vec{x} \le b$ where $b \in \mathbb K$.

Comment: https://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~pouchet.2/lectures/doc/888.11.1.pdf

Comment: From the given link. Introduction to polyhedral model

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net From the given link. Introduction to polyhedral model